# ASP Net Permissions on Win 8.1 to allow web users to save File?

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions

I'm working on a website which uses ASP.NET and IIS 8.5.

The site is currently running on my dev machine (standard win 8.1 laptop) and I can browse in general around the site absolutely fine.

My problem comes when the user tries to save a file to a folder. I get the error:
`Access to the folder blah is denied`

Having searched around the web I've found the solution to this is to grant write permissions on the folder to the user ASP.NET uses.

I've granted write permissions to the I_USERS group, the App Pool User and the Network Service, but this still hasn't solved the issue.

I've also seen that the user ASPNET must be added to the permissions too, however I don't seem to have that user on my machine. -Is this why I am getting the error, or is it something else completely?

Some Code:

Markup:

```
    <div class="col-sm-10" Style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
         <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader" style="width:100%" runat="server" CssClass="text" />
    </div>  

        /*****Some other controls (eg.textboxes) here *****/

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <asp:Button ID="uploadBTN" runat="server" CssClass="frbtn" OnClick="uploadBTN_Click" Text="Upload Video" Style="width: 20%; float: right;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void uploadBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUploader.SaveAs(FRConfig.VideoFolder); //This bit does the saving
        Video v = new Video(FileUploader.FileName, fileDescripTB.Text);//This saves the video data to a database.
        Helpers.Show("Video Uploaded Successfully!"); //This launches an alert to state it has been sucessfully uploaded.
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: Could you add some code to your question to show how/where you are trying to save a file?

Comment: Added, let me know if there's anything else I should add, I'm used to developing WPF apps so I'm not sure whats relevant when it comes to ASP.NET!

Comment: Where does "FRConfig.VideoFolder" point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the IIS defaults, granting write permissions to `IIS_IUSRS` should be enough. The `App Pool User` is automatically a member of `IIS_IUSRS`, `Network Service` is only needed if you change the identity of the application pool.

The following aspx pages tests write permissions for the default web site:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" debug="true"%>
<script runat="server">
   void Page_Load() {
      System.IO.File.Copy(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iis-85.png",@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\new.png",true);
   }
</script>
```

You should not allow write access to locations under your web root, place file uploads into a different directory.